# Is this table in my ERD redundant? (Image)

Tags: mysql, database-design, erd

I am developing a research article database for a project. My professor approved this design but I feel like the Author's_University table is redundant and that University_ID could just be added to the Articles_Authored table. Can anyone think of a reason to NOT change it?

Thanks for the input.

[image: Database Design]

Comment: `Keyword_ID` and `Topic_ID` may come under the category of "overnormalization".

Comment: @RickJames I told my professor the same thing but he disagreed. Couldn't I just have the names being the only attribute in each table since there will never be 2 keywords or topics with same name?

Comment: That's even better -- Generally if a relation is 1:1, put both sets in the same table.  (Exceptions usually involve subtle performance issues, wide columns, etc.)

Comment: Apparently your professor has not build large systems in the "real world".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of the `Author's_University` table seems to be to allow one author on an article to be associated with more than one university. There are a couple of potential reasons why that would be helpful:

- An author might claim multiple universities because they are a professor and/or are associated with more than one university when the article was published.
- Your application might want to track an author's alma mater(s).

---

I know this isn't part of your question but I would avoid putting an apostrophe in a table name. Removing the apostrophe would change `Author's_University` to `Authors_University` or just `Author_University` (my preference). That will most likely make the table easier to work with because punctuation isn't your friend when naming.

Also, my personal preference is `PascalCase` over `Snake_Case`. That is merely personal preference though, and might clash with the convention in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was conflicted with a classmate regarding the naming conventions. I like Pascal more myself. I have updated the ERD. Thanks again!